# Response.OutputStream.Flush() - not responding

Tags: c#, video-streaming

I am streaming a video using handler (ashx) file,

Get video file stream and Writing bytes using outputstream in while loop,
But received bytes is zero only until the while loop complete.

```
public class VideoHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        System.Net.WebRequest wreq;
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse wresp;
        try
        {
            HttpRequest Request = context.Request;

            string OrginalUrl = GetURL();

            wreq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(OrginalUrl);
            wreq.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60;
            wresp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse();


            using (Stream mystream = wresp.GetResponseStream())
            {

                int length = Convert.ToInt32(wresp.ContentLength);

                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.Buffer = false;
                context.Response.BufferOutput = false;

                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());

                byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

                if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    while (mystream.CanRead)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = mystream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (bytesRead == 0) break;

                        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                        context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                    }
                }


                String DateValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                mystream.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            wresp = null;
            wreq = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my handler file, What I am missing here?

This my HTML

```
<video id="videoPlayer1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="700" height="500"
                    data-height="500" autoplay="autoplay" >
                    <source id="source1" src="Handlers/VideoHandler.ashx" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you closing the output stream inside the `while` -loop?

Comment: Why are you swallowing all exceptions?

Comment: Just tried this 'context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();' but no luck.

Comment: @SumoS why didn't you try what the answer and the comments suggested?

Comment: removed this (context.Response.OutputStream.Close()) line but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
context.Response.Flush();
```

directly. And do *not* `Close` the output stream.

All in all, you shouldn't need the flushing at all, when buffering is off.

You should set the proper Content-Type as well - HTML5 video players tend to be quite finicky about that. `application/octet-stream` likely won't cut it.

And of course, you'd want to have support for partial downloads, it's quite handy when serving long video files :)

Comment: I added(context.Response.Flush()) in the loop but no luck.

Comment: You should set the proper Content-Encoding - here what u mean?

Comment: @SumoS I meant content type. For example, `video/mp4` for MP4 video.

Comment: Luaan, Thank u for your quick response, I have tried that no luck.

Comment: @SumoS Oh, and why are you sending data from another HTTP request? What's the point of that? Why not just do a redirect? That's just another point where you're losing the "streaming" (not that you're actually doing any streaming at all). Also, have you tried using developer tools or Wireshark to monitor the actual communication? Why do you think the `while` is to blame?

Comment: 'Why not just do a redirect?'. Can you please guide me how to redirect it.

Comment: Great Luann, Its working fine. My requirement is users should not able able to download video from my page, In this case it can be downloadable.

Comment: @SumoS The video is going through the browser - you'll *always* be capable of downloading it. That's the reason why YouTube and others send as little of the video as possible, instead of sending it all in one package - and even that means only that you have to more or less "watch" the whole video, not that it's impossible to download it :)

Comment: Thanks @Luaan, That is why I am writing as bytes in output stream.

Comment: @SumoS That doesn't help at all - you're still just sending data to the browser. The browser can still save that data and replay it later. The only thing you've done is that you've hidden the original URL - that doesn't help much.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Luaan, It was most helpful.